# How I can hide only one variable in .htacces

Tags: .htaccess

I need hide only one variable from get request my url:

```
http://example.com/profile/?id=5&username=demo
```

I trying to make:

```
http://example.com/player/demo
```

htaccess:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l

RewriteRule ^player/([^/]*)$ /profile/?id=$1&username=$2 [QSA,B]
```

Answer (score 0):

My solution here is to change

`http://example.com/profile/?id=5&username=demo`

to

`http://example.com/player/5/demo`

because if you use what you suggested

`http://example.com/player/demo`

there is an indication to `username` which is `demo` but there is no indication to `id` unless you do it like following :

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-l
RewriteRule ^player/(.*)/(.*)$ /profile/?id=$1&username=$2 [QSA,L]
```

Comment: But i need hide id

Comment: Its value is fixed or will change؟

Comment: its user id is not fixed value

Comment: ok , just think of that , if request  http://example.com/profile/?id=5&username=demo be this  http://example.com/player/demo , then another reguest  http://example.com/profile/?id=6&username=demo with id 6 will be also http://example.com/player/demo , so when user request http://example.com/player/demo how server determine whether ID is 5 or 6 ?